# Delphi fastest FileSize for sizes > 10gb

Tags: delphi, winapi

Wanted to check with you experts if there are any drawbacks in this funtion. Will it work properly on the various Windows OS ? I am using Delphi Seattle (32 and 64 bit exe's). I am using this instead of Findfirst for its speed.

```
function GetFileDetailsFromAttr(pFileName:WideString):int64;
var
  wfad: TWin32FileAttributeData;
  wSize:LARGE_INTEGER ;
begin
  Result:=0 ;
  if not GetFileAttributesEx(pwidechar(pFileName), GetFileExInfoStandard,@wfad) then
    exit;

  wSize.HighPart:=wfad.nFileSizeHigh ;
  wSize.LowPart:=wfad.nFileSizeLow  ;
  result:=wsize.QuadPart ;
end;
```

The typical googled samples shown with this command does not work for filesize > 9GB

```
function GetFileAttributesEx():Int64 using 
begin
...
  result:=((&wfad.nFileSizeHigh) or (&wfad.nFileSizeLow))
```

Comment: The 2nd example is wrong, as it is not shifting the bits of the `nFileSizeHigh`, eg: `Result := (Int64(wfad.nFileSizeHigh) shl 32) or wfad.nFileSizeLow;` in the 1st example, the `LARGE_INTEGER` handles that for you

Comment: Emm... Way with QuadPart is correct. Way with `or` is definitely wrong. Why do you show the last code piece?

Comment: Also, you should be using `UnicodeString` instead of `WideString` in D2009+. `WideString` is an ActiveX/COM string, and is less performant than `UnicodeString`. As for OS support, `GetFileAttributesEx` has been around since XP.

Comment: @MBo  Most of the code available on the internet is using similar code and you'll may think I have not researched therefore I showed that code. eg:  https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/119049/Getting-size-of-a-file-in-Delphi-2010-or-later  this link shows similar example but does not work for large files

Comment: Thanks for the UnicodeString tip @Remy will check this out

Comment: `GetFileAttributes` isn't just faster than `FindFirstFile`, it also won't fail in obscure ways: See [Superstition: Why is GetFileAttributes the way old-timers test file existence?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071023-00/?p=24713)

Comment: I yet see no hint in what @KedarVerma means by "in this funtion": his own with his code in it, or `GetFileAttributesEx()` alone without his code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code with variant record is correct.

But this code

```
result:=((&wfad.nFileSizeHigh) or (&wfad.nFileSizeLow))
```

is just wrong, result cannot overcome 32-bit border

Code from link in comment

```
result := Int64(info.nFileSizeLow) or Int64(info.nFileSizeHigh shl 32);
```

is wrong because it does not account how compiler works with 32 and 64-bit values. Look at the next example showing how to treat this situation properly (for value d, e):

```
var
  a, b: DWord;
  c, d, e: Int64;
  wSize:LARGE_INTEGER ;
begin
  a := 1;
  b := 1;
  c := Int64(a) or Int64(b shl 32);
  d := Int64(a) or Int64(b) shl 32;
  wSize.LowPart := a;
  wSize.HighPart := b;
  e := wsize.QuadPart;
  Caption := Format('$%x $%x  $%x', [c, d, e]);
```

Note that in the expression for `c` 32-bit value is shifted by 32 bits left and **looses** set bit, then zero transforms to 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Unbound to how you get the filesize: it would even be faster if you'd use a type ([manual](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_Int64Rec.html)) that exists for ~25 years already to assign the filesize directly to the function's result instead of using an intermediate variable:

```
  Int64Rec(result).Hi:= wfad.nFileSizeHigh;
  Int64Rec(result).Lo:= wfad.nFileSizeLow;
end;
```

In case this isn't obvious to anyone here's what the compilation looks like:

[image: with intermediate variable]

Above: the intermediate variable `w: LARGE_INTEGER` first gets assigned the two 32bit parts and then is assigned itself to the function's result. Cost: 10 instructions.

[image: using record on function result directly]

Above: the record `Int64Rec` is used to cast the function's result and assign both 32bit parts directly, without the need of any other variable. Cost: 6 instructions.

Environment used: Delphi 7.0 (Build 8.1), compiler version 15.0, Win32 executable, code optimization: on.

Comment: Why would this be faster?

Comment: This is no faster.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so using an intermediate variable comes at no cost?

Comment: Not compared to the cost of finding the size of a file

Comment: I've edited my answer to underline that I understood OP's question to how the filesize was assigned to the function's result, not how it was actually retrieved.

Comment: Have you verified, and concluded, that there even is **any** difference in the optimized code? It's not like this is some advanced, cutting-edge optimization opportunity. It's something we've had literally for decades.

Comment: That's double standards: one cannot argue that this is not faster by comparing it to code I've never touched and the possibility that the/every compiler would optimize it. It is faster both by logic and by theory. However: yes, I haven't tested this on Seattle, neither 32 nor 64 bit (I can't).

Comment: The onus is on you to show that it is faster, not us. You are the one with the answer making that claim.