# use Delphi to read in a text file to a TStringList but bottom to top

Tags: delphi, reverse, tstringlist

I was looking to read a text file in reverse so it would read in from the bottom of the text file first. I did find how to reverse it but it doesn't make sense to me. Can someone explain this to me, how it's working? Also if there is a better/quicker way? It seems to do all the work after the file is read in, like it would be quicker to just read it in from the bottom.

```pascal
var
  datalist : TStringList;
  lines,i  : Integer;
  saveLine : String;
begin
  datalist := TStringList.Create;
  datalist.LoadFromFile(filename);   //loads file
  lines := datalist.Count;

  for i := lines-1 downto (lines div 2) do
    begin
      saveLine := datalist[lines-i-1];
      datalist[lines-i-1] := datalist[i];
      datalist[i] := saveLine;
    end;
```

Comment: Counter question: can files be read in reverse at all? Also you might want to use [`.Exchange()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Exchange) to exchange lines.

Comment: @AmigoJack Yes they can be read in reverse. You just go to the end and read in chunks moving the file pointer backwards.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's the whole point - you still read the chunks (or even every single byte) in one way: forwards. Never backwards. That approach is always flawed.

Comment: I think I'd make a `TStrings` sub-class accepted another `TStrings` instance and implemented `GetItem(Index)` with `Source.GetItem(Count - Index - 1)`

Comment: @AmigoJack Why is it flawed? Would work perfectly well and could be just as fast as forwards.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan [Unless proven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473800/delphi-fastest-filesize-for-sizes-10gb/63474496#comment112273578_63474496) I'm convinced by my experience that reading backwards is always slower. Reading forwards needs no file seeks, backwards always, which adds expense.

Comment: @AmigoJack Seeking is inexpensive on SSDs, or am I wrong. Also, disk cache.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Now those are requirements you come up with late. If the media doesn't have both your arguments fall apart. Otherwise tell me why no OS implements a file system read that does just that. I wouldn't have expected such a reasoning by you, lazily ignoring non up-to-date standards.

Comment: This is my thought on it. A file is just data, wither its on line 1 or line 50000 it should take the same effort to locate that data. but something somewhere has to be telling it to default at the top and go down. In theory if that something is saying default at bottom and go up, it should be no difference in speed.  Personally i thought each program read the data how it was set in default. for example notepad, when you open a file it tells it to get data from memory at this point and then +1 .  if it did get data from this point then -1 then same speed.  Just my thinking..

Comment: @user41758 Amigo is correct that the OS and devices and programming libraries are designed with a forward reading mentality. I believe that you can achieve decent performance reading backwards but it takes care and attention. But as I suggested above and in my answer, I think it is actually better to read forwards, but then present a virtualised reversed view onto the list of items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(At least in Delphi 7, but more recent versions should act similarily)

1. [`.LoadFromFile()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.LoadFromFile) calls
2. [`.LoadFromStream()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.LoadFromStream), which reads the whole stream/file into memory and then calls
3. `.SetTextStr()`, which just calls per line
4. [`.Add()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Add)

Knowing this helps us to avoiding to reinvent the whole wheel and instead using an own class with one subtle change in the `.Add()` method:

```pascal
type
  TStringListReverse= class( TStringList )
    function Add( const S: String ): Integer; override;
  end;

function TStringListReverse.Add( const S: String ): Integer;
begin
  Result:= {GetCount} 0;  // Our change: always in front
  Insert( Result, S );
end;
```

And now we just use our own class:

```pascal
var
  l: TStringListReverse;
begin
  l:= TStringListReverse.Create;
  l.LoadFromFile( 'C:\Windows\win.ini' );
  Memo1.Lines.Assign( l );
  l.Free;
```

Comment: Just note that this is going to drop efficiency a bit since it has to shuffle the `TStringList`'s entire internal array every time it inserts a new string at the front of the array rather than at the back.

Answer (score 3):

As I mentioned in a comment, it might be useful to create an adapter class that accepts a `TStrings` instance, and exposes it as another `TStrings`, but reversed.

This might look like this:

```
type
  TReversedStrings = class(TStrings)
  private
    FSource: TStrings;
    FOwnsSource: Boolean;
    function ReversedIndex(Index: Integer): Integer;
  protected
    procedure Put(Index: Integer; const S: string); override;
    function Get(Index: Integer): string; override;
    function GetCount: Integer; override;
    function GetObject(Index: Integer): TObject; override;
    procedure PutObject(Index: Integer; AObject: TObject); override;
  public
    constructor Create(Source: TStrings; AssumeOwnership: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Clear; override;
    procedure Delete(Index: Integer); override;
    procedure Exchange(Index1, Index2: Integer); override;
    function IndexOf(const S: string): Integer; override;
    procedure Insert(Index: Integer; const S: string); override;
    procedure Move(CurIndex, NewIndex: Integer); override;
  end;

{ TReversedStrings }

constructor TReversedStrings.Create(Source: TStrings; AssumeOwnership: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FSource := Source;
  FOwnsSource := AssumeOwnership;
end;

destructor TReversedStrings.Destroy;
begin
  if FOwnsSource then
    FSource.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TReversedStrings.ReversedIndex(Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := FSource.Count - Index - 1;
end;

procedure TReversedStrings.Put(Index: Integer; const S: string);
begin
  FSource[ReversedIndex(Index)] := S;
end;

function TReversedStrings.Get(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := FSource[ReversedIndex(Index)];
end;

function TReversedStrings.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FSource.Count;
end;

function TReversedStrings.GetObject(Index: Integer): TObject;
begin
  Result := FSource.Objects[ReversedIndex(Index)];
end;

procedure TReversedStrings.PutObject(Index: Integer; AObject: TObject);
begin
  FSource.Objects[ReversedIndex(Index)] := AObject;
end;

procedure TReversedStrings.Clear;
begin
  FSource.Clear;
end;

procedure TReversedStrings.Delete(Index: Integer);
begin
  FSource.Delete(ReversedIndex(Index));
end;

procedure TReversedStrings.Exchange(Index1, Index2: Integer);
begin
  FSource.Exchange(ReversedIndex(Index1), ReversedIndex(Index2));
end;

function TReversedStrings.IndexOf(const S: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := FSource.IndexOf(S);
  if Result > -1 then
    Result := ReversedIndex(Result);
end;

procedure TReversedStrings.Insert(Index: Integer; const S: string);
begin
  FSource.Insert(ReversedIndex(Index), S);
end;

procedure TReversedStrings.Move(CurIndex, NewIndex: Integer);
begin
  FSource.Move(ReversedIndex(CurIndex), ReversedIndex(NewIndex));
end;
```

It should be obvious how to use this, and I've not tested the code, or even executed it. Consider it a sketch of an idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `TStringList.LoadFromFile()` function, then another way to do it is to copy one `TStringList` to another `TStringList`.  It would be faster than the current scheme, and is fewer lines of code.

```
var
  datalist1, datalist2 : TStringList;
  lines, i: Integer;
  filename : string;
begin
  datalist1 := TStringList.Create;
  datalist2 := TStringList.Create;
  datalist1.LoadFromFile(filename);   //loads file
  lines := datalist1.Count;
  data2list.Capacity := lines;  // so it allocates the memory once
  for i := lines-1 downto 0 do
  begin
    datalist2.Add (datalist1[i]);
  end;

end;
```

Personally, I would read the file in myself.

Comment: This example lacks the stringlist creation!

Comment: Also, this code can be made faster by setting the `datalist2.Capacity` property before entering the loop: `datalist2.Capacity := lines;`

Comment: @DelphiCoder - yes it does it was meant as a fragment, to illustrate it

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Good point, I will update it both things.